# SwiftUI - Dynamic segmented Picker Filter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to build a dynamic Picker with a segmented style that re-renders itself based on user input.

So in other words, every time the user adds a value to the `filterValues` array the segmented picker should re-render.

This what I tried and not working:[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State private var items = [Item]()
   @State private var filterValueIndex = 0
   @State private var filterValues: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 5]

   var body: some View {
       Picker("Filter", selection: $filterValueIndex) {
            ForEach(0 ..< filterValues.count) {
                Text("\(filterValues[$0])")
            }
        }
       .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use dynamic `ForEach` for that as below (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

```
    Picker("Filter", selection: $filterValueIndex) {
            ForEach(filterValues.indices, id: \.self) {    // << here !!
                 Text("\(filterValues[$0])")
            }
      }
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```